# KDE Dashboard settings don't show up

Tags: kde4, widgets, plasma

I'm using the Widget Dashboard in KDE4. When I right-click it and select "Desktop Dashboard Settings", nothing happens. No window shows up on none of my desktops.

What is the matter here?

I'm using Kubuntu Raring (Ubuntu with `kubuntu-desktop` installed and Unity purged. And I know it's EoL, I'm going to reinstall when Trusty is out)

Comment: the problem still exists in trusty, isn't it possible to reach the dashboard settings somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unfixed bug.

Maybe you want to comment on that bug in the KDE bugtracker to push it's importance:
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=294018